# A question about main routine and a child routine listening on the same channel simultaneously

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    stop := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        defer func() { stop <- true }()
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                fmt.Println("Tick")
            case <-stop:
                fmt.Println("Goroutine closing")
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    <-c
    ticker.Stop()

    stop <- true

    <-stop
    fmt.Println("Application stopped")
}
```

No matter how many times I run the code above, I got the same result. That is, "Goroutine closing" is always printed before "Application stopped" after I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I think, theoretically, there is a chance that "Goroutine closing" won't be printed at all. Am I right? Unfortunately, I never get this theoretical result.

BTW: I know reading and writing a channel in one routine should be avoided. Ignore that temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, `Goroutine closing` will always be executed and it will always be printed before `Application stopped`, because your `stop` channel is not buffered. This means that the sending will block until the result is received.

In your code, the `stop <- true` in your `main` will block until the goroutine has received the value, causing the channel to be empty again. Then the `<-stop` in your main will block until another value is sent to the channel, which happens when your goroutine returns after printing `Goroutine closing`.

If you would initialize your channel in a buffered fashion

```
stop := make(chan bool, 1)
```

then `Goroutine closing` might not be executed. To see this, you can add a [`time.Sleep`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep) right after printing `Tick`, as this makes this case more likely (it will occur everytime you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> during the sleep).

Using a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to wait for goroutines to finish is a good alternative, especially if you have to wait for more than one goroutine. You can also use a [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) to stop goroutines. Reworking your code to use these two methods could look something like this:

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer func() { wg.Done() }()
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                fmt.Println("Goroutine closing")
                return
            case <-ticker.C:
                fmt.Println("Tick")
                time.Sleep(time.Second)
            }
        }
    }()

    <-c
    ticker.Stop()

    cancel()

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("Application stopped")
}
```